# How does this static variable declaration return infinity?

Tags: c#, math, syntax

I'm trying to port some C# code (the Chipmunk physics engine) to Xojo.

In a class declaration, there are two public static variables declared:

```
public static byte[] INFINITY = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x7F };

public static float Infinity
{
    get
    {
        return BitConverter.ToSingle(INFINITY, 0);
    }
}
```

By my understanding, from the MSDN docs, a call to the static variable `Infinity` should return a single-precision floating point number formed by four bytes beginning at index 0, i.e. should return `0x0000807F` as a 32-bit integer. Isn't that `32895`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this bytes is a representation of a low level storing float data:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Also, this is a very usable online calculator of IEEE format:
http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Try to set a "Hexadecimal Representation" to 0x7f800000, and you get "Infinity" in "After casting to double precision" box.

By the way, the value is 0x7f800000, not a 0x0000807f because of little endian order of bytes in memory.